# Why does React need to call the same number of hooks each render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Various errors can be triggered from React when there is either a change in the number of hooks, or the order in which hooks are called changes. React documents these limitations/rules [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and also documents ways to fix the various errors.

I understand that these rules exist, but *why* do they exist?
The above page states

> React relies on the order in which Hooks are called

but why did the React team decide to rely on what appears to be be an array-like structure rather than a keyed object to access hook calls? There doesn't seem to be any React documentation that details if this even *was* a design decision or if it's inherent to the way hooks have to work 'under-the-hood'.

Comment: because of how hooks is implemented. I'm pretty sure hooks uses closures to track state and updates them based on their call order.

Comment: Think of `useState`. You don't pass it any identifiers. How does react know which state to retrieve in the case that `useState` is called more than once? By the order of the calls. If you vary the order (by, for instance, conditionally using a hook), then this ordering breaks down.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJP1E-Y-xyo gives a great explanation on how hooks work in react.

Comment: @spender surely React does have the ability to add its own identifiers internally? My question is why did they choose to track via order?

Comment: @Tom "_surely React does have the ability to add its own identifiers internally?_": Yes, of course, but how could it possibly generate and associate a unique AND persistent identifier to each function invocation without some deterministic variable to link the association? It can't, and that variable is the order of invocation. (Compare this with the ID parameter used with an instance of [`atomFamily`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/utils/atomFamily) in Recoil.)

Comment: @jsejcksn Isn't what you wrote above self-contradictive? You say it can't create unique and persistent identifiers to each function, but then you say the variable it creates is the order of invocation. So it can create one, based on the invocation order, right? Clearly hooks can handle mounting and unmounting of components so there must also be a way to handle hook count and order changes in general

Comment: @Tom That's correct: the unique identifier is each invocation's position in the series of all invocations: this type of position in an ordered series is also called an index, which is what is used for keys in an array in JavaScript. This is why the invocations must be unconditional.

Comment: Components are just functions. There is nothing stopping you from doing `<MyComponent bool />` or `MyComponent({bool: true})`. It will render just right. However, when that component has a hook, it will suddenly break, because React stores the order of hooks per component (that is `React.createElement` call). This is why you can dynamically (un)mount trees and it won't break.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the order is very important.

I can only guess why they choose to do it like this.

You component is just a function actually. The hooks are defined outside of your component (function) so when a hook is called (for instance a `useState`) they need a way to identify which hook is being called so they can return the same `setState` every time.

They could've added an identifier to the call, but it would've been your responsibility to pass unique identifiers to this call. Even more the id needs to be unique in the **entire** view tree. This means that you should've define a way to have unique ids in the entire application.

Using the order fixes this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a problem, but a design pattern decision. If they'd chosen to use a cache keyed by ID, then state could be shared without prop drilling (i.e. Recoil's [`atomFamily`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/utils/atomFamily)), which could be quite beneficial, but adds complexity for the developer in cases where it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the explanation is right here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

**From the documentation details :**

> React relies on the order in which Hooks are called

> If we want to run an effect conditionally, we can put that condition inside our Hook

This is so each components maintains its state consistently.
It avoids errors like call on undefined hook or effect variable and total component re-render if the state isn't maintained properly.

Comment: I was looking for a deeper explanation of that. Why does react rely/need to rely on the order in which hooks are called?

Answer (score 0):

Since we can use multiple hooks in a single component, React needs a stable way to call them correctly, in the *right order*. Think about it this way: You start your component with a `useState()`, which contains data that will be used across re-renders. What will React do if you remove the hook? Where should the data go? Where should the state go? React is not designed for such use cases.

How it does work, though, is by **relying on the order in which Hooks are called**. Did you notice that the hooks are just functions, without any sort of order parameters? The way React can know in which order to call them, is by keeping track of *in which order you wrote them*. Removing a hook would break this order and create inconsistencies and errors.

On the page you have linked, there is an [explanation section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), which further answers your question with a good example.